# How can I optimize Dart code heavy on if statements?

Tags: optimization, dart

I'm new to the Dart programming language, and I turned to my usual test, FizzBuzz, to check out the language. At the moment, I've got this relatively `if`-heavy example, which is pretty slow. Just dropping one if statements takes the execution time from 36 seconds to 25 seconds on my MacBook Pro, with 5000000 loops. I was wondering the ways I could optimize it further.

```
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    var num = i + 1;
    if (num % 15 == 0) {
      print('FizzBuzz');
      continue;
    }
    if (num % 5 == 0) {
      print('Buzz');
      continue;
    }
    if (num % 3 == 0) {
      print('Fizz');
      continue;
    }
    print(num);
  }
}
```

I tried wrapping it all in a `switch` statement, as follows, but it doesn't compile to JS, and DartPad gives the error `Type 'int' of the switch expression isn't assignable to the type 'bool' of case expressions.`

```
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    var num = i + 1;
    switch (num) {
      case (num % 15 == 0):
        print('FizzBuzz');
        break;
      case (num % 5 == 0):
        print('Buzz');
        break;
      case (num % 3 == 0):
        print('Fizz');
        break;
      default:
        print(num);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You can omit the first `if` and swap the remaining two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num` is a type of a built in type (common super type of `int` and `double`), also the `case ...:` expression needs to be constant and therefore can't be calculated based on non-constant values.

I think using `if` is the best option.

Comment: Ahh, alright, thanks. Do you have any suggestions about optimizing the current `if` solution? (also, I tried upvoting your post, but I couldn't due to lack of reputation - much thanks)

Comment: Why ate you using `var num = i + 1;`? With `for (int i = 1; i < 5000001; i++) {` you could drop it.

Comment: You could skip `if (num % 15 == 0) {` if `num % 3` and `num % 5` are `!= 0`.

Comment: You could also keep track how many numbers you added and tkip the modulo calculation entirely. You know that after incrementing another 3 `% 3` will be 0 (same for 5 and 15)

Answer (score 0):

Printing to console becomes a non-trivial operation when performance testing like this. With your code you are testing the speed of print here more than anything. The conditional statements and increments are a fraction of your running time.

Try the following:

```
import 'dart:async';

main(){
  // mark the start of go
  var begin = DateTime.now();
  go();
  //mark the time that go completes and goZoned begins
  var midpoint = DateTime.now();
  goZoned();
  // mark the end of goZoned
  var end = DateTime.now();
  print("done:\n$begin\n$midpoint\n$end");
}

// This function runs the go function, but short-circuits any calls to print
// with a no-op
void goZoned() {
  runZoned(() {
    go();
  }, zoneSpecification: new ZoneSpecification(
      print: (Zone self, ZoneDelegate parent, Zone zone, String line) {}
      )
  );
}

void go(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
      var num = i + 1;
      if (num % 15 == 0) {
        print('FizzBuzz');
        continue;
      }
      if (num % 5 == 0) {
        print('Buzz');
        continue;
      }
      if (num % 3 == 0) {
        print('Fizz');
        continue;
      }
      print(num);
    }
}
```

The results on my machine were

```
done:
2018-09-10 10:33:23.012086
2018-09-10 10:33:33.407191
2018-09-10 10:33:33.827196
```

You can see that the execution with print statements took over 10 seconds, but without print statements took a little more than a third of a second.

(wall time is still a very crude method of measuring run time, but does the job here)